# Android: Trying to change width of TextView at runtime

Tags: android

I have a textView that I'm trying to change the size at runtime. But the size does not chnage.

The code in the xml file

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textScreenWidth"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12dp"
```

code on OnCreat to change the the size

```
TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScreenWidth); 
    t.setWidth(950);
```

the size does not change

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`t.getLayoutParams().width = 950;`