# Android: Trying to change width of TextView

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a textView that I'm trying to change the size at runtime.

The code in the xml file

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textScreenWidth"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12dp"
```

Code on OnCreat to change the the size

```
TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScreenWidth); 
    t.setWidth(950);
```

the size does not change

Comment: what is the parent view of the TextView?

Comment: You have around long enough to know that repeating your question is not acceptable. [Android: Trying to change width of TextView at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189979/android-trying-to-change-width-of-textview-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
txtView.setLayoutParams(lParams);
```

This assuming your parent layout is a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set like this

```
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(950,30); // Width , height
    t.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

Comment: actually setWidth must work, but maybe some thing at the father view is preventing the editing.